# User Control As Owner

Tags: c#, wpf

I have window form in my WPF Application when I open new window from my form I used to set the owner of the new window to my opening window. But when I have converted the parent window to user control the line

```
objSearchCareGiver.Owner = this;
```

gives error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyNameSpace.ucUserControlto 'System.Windows.Window'
```

can anyone explain why is this so?

Comment: Could you specify what error you get? It would help people give you more accurate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you get a runtime error or compile-time error?  I'm guessing your error is because the `Window.Owner` property is of type `Window` and user controls aren't valid.  Even if a user control is a subclass of `Window` it may be that user controls can't own child windows.  Specifically, if you look at [the documentation for the Window.Owner property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), it talks about the property establishing a relationship between the parent and the child form.  This relationship mostly has to to with propagating visual changes from the parent to the child (e.g., closing the child window automatically when the parent window is closed, minimizing the child when the parent is minimized).  These behaviors don't really make sense with a user control as the parent.

Comment: In that case, though I can't be sure because you haven't posted the specific error, I'd assume user controls are incompatible with the `Window` type.  Therefore, you simply can't assign a user control as the owner of a `Window`, because `Window.Owner` must itself be a `Window`.